# Istio virtual service regex uri is not working

Tags: regex, kubernetes, istio, istio-gateway

Inside the virtual service, I have routed 2 paths to my service as follows -

```yaml
- match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /jaeger/
    - uri:
        regex: \/oauth2\/.*jaeger.*
    route:
    - destination:
        host: oauth2-proxy
        port:
          number: 80
```

But the gateway returns 404 when I send request on the path `/oauth2/callback?code=3QxQLUqCwxVtH_GS6mWteICfisIe32yE7RE6wQIZZVw&state=wmZSZ0BHMHq3vmS_1YBWIn72pG6FkChFQbNUNipGotQ%3A%2Fjaeger%2F`

Now, I could also just use the prefix `/oauth2/` to handle such URLs but currently I have multiple applications that are being authenticated by their own oauth2-proxies and this regex would match all of them. So I need to use a regex which contains the application name inside it, such as jaeger is this case.

I even checked on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) that this path is indeed matching the regex I used.

Also, the gateway routes the request successfully when I use the regex `\/oauth2\/.*`. But as I explained I can't use this regex either. Am I missing something here?

Edit:
After further testing, I found out that if remove the "?" from the path, istio accepts this as valid and forwards the request to the service.
I also tried the regex `/oauth2\/callback\?code=.*jaeger.*` but that isn't working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not realize that "?" marks the end of a URL and everything after that are query parameters. Istio provides matching of query parameters as well. The following code worked in my case -

```
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /jaeger/
    - uri:
        regex: \/oauth2\/callback?.*
      queryParams:
        state: 
          regex: .*jaeger.*
    route:
    - destination:
        host: oauth2-proxy
        port:
          number: 80
```